# Pushdown Automaton to accept all strings such that no prefix has more 1’s than 0’s

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata

> Design a Pushdown Automata, accepting either by final state or by
>   empty stack to accept the set of all strings of 0’s and 1’s such that
>   no prefix has more 1’s than 0’s

This is a homework question, but not graded.

I'm not looking for the answer, right now I'm just trying to understand the question. I don't understand what sort of words would be accepted and what would be rejected. For example, I can't understand whether the following word would be accepted:

- 011011 ; where 01 is prefix and 1011 is suffix
- 011011 ; where 011
  is prefix and 011 is suffix
- 011011 ; where 0110 is prefix and 11 is
  suffix

**My question is: Given a word, how do I know which part of it is the prefix?**

Please try to give an explanation without the actual PDA answer, I'd like to try it myself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a word, $w=a_1a_2\dots a_n$ where the $a_i$ are characters from the underlying alphabet, then the prefixes of $w$ are the empty word, $\epsilon$, and the words $a_1$, $a_1a_2$, $a_1a_2a_3$, ..., $a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}a_n$. In informal terms, the prefixes of a word consist of all left-hand segments of the word.